# Why does rectifier output is showing DC instead of pulsating DC

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, inductor, ac-dc, power-factor-correction

I am using below circuit for PFC.
Before connecting coupled inductor's auxiliary output to the IC's Vcc, I wanted to make sure that it is coming properly or not.

So when I probed the red dot in the circuit below, it is showing 0V, doubtfully when I probed blue dot in the circuit below, Instead of pulsating DC at the point, I am observing a 312VDC, straight line. I am suspecting that may be the reason the inductor is not giving any voltage to it's auxiliary winding because there is no change in current at the primary winding.
(The measurement of the voltage is done in oscilloscope).

[image]

Comment: If there is no or very little current taken from the capacitor, it is perfectly normal that the 'blue' dot is a 'straight line'. What is your load?

Comment: I have not connected any load

Comment: No load might explain why the unit is not switching (The C6 is fully charged and nothing is taken out) which again would explain your 0 V on the red dot. I suggest you put a simple load resistor on the output and then start measuring again.

Comment: I have connected 400W electric bulb as load. But the red dot is still 0V, but at blue dot the voltage is rectified full wave.

Comment: I have not connected the IC to the any part of the circuit. I wanted to make sure that the auxiliary winding is giving proper voltage or not. So I have disconnected all the connections of IC with the auxiliary winding.

Comment: You have just take the core controller out of the system , which means nothing will be switching. How do you expect to get anything out of the auxiliary winding with only DC going through the transformer? Also you have connected a 400W load to an output which is marked as 250W. Your are working with dangerous voltages. From all that, at this point I would advise you get help from a local expert.

Comment: Without auxiliary winding giving any voltage how can I expect the IC will turn ON. That is why I have not connected the Vcc, to see whether auxiliary winding gives any voltage or not. Yes switching is not present, but the inductor should operate right, because voltage is pulsating DC.